# Use cases for a unique metric

Tags: outliers, metric

So I was thinking about this question:
[Maximum minus average?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118060/maximum-minus-average)

**This question is on hold while work calls me.  When I get a chance I am going to substantially update it.**

**Background:**

At my previous job, I was able to find a metric that started triggering (onset of sensitivity) at 1.15 standard deviations from the mean, and reliably triggered above 1.54 standard deviations. The metric of Mean-to-max has onset at about 2.84 standard deviations, and the metric min-to-max has onset at about 2.69 standard deviations.  This was applied to pre-reflow solder-ball coplanarity as a predictor of solder-joint reliability after reflow.  The idea was that a pre-reflow outlier would not behave as it should and would cause itself (if too small) or its neighbors (if too large) to not reflow properly.

**The Question/s:**

- What are some real-world use cases where "this thing isn't like its
  normally-distributed neighbors" detection is useful?  (outside of solder-balls)
- Are there metrics that have sensitivity on 1200 samples of a normally
  distributed phenomena that can detect outlierhood at thresholds below
  1.15 standard deviations from the mean?  If so, what are they?  How do they work?  What is their onset of sensitivity?  At what level of variation does the signal unilaterally emerge from noise?
- How do I determine whether something like this might be valuable to "the community of (statistics-oriented) scholars"?

Comment: Starting with a statistic seems kind of backwards. It usually is more fruitful to begin with a problem and use statistical principles to derive appropriate decision procedures, rather than to begin with a statistic and ask what it might be good for. This one is particularly suspect as a useful statistic for two reasons: (1) the variability of the maximum will be large and therefore the difference between the max and average is likely to lead to [inadmissible tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_decision_rule); and (2) a single high outlier will totally screw up the value.

Comment: After 1.54 standard deviations from the mean, the false-positive rate went to zero.  The outlier is what was trying to be detected, selected, and removed.  I would want a test to flag on it.

Comment: Are you asking about how to detect outliers?  If so, we need to have much more context, because what constitutes an outlier depends on the form of the analysis. An additional point of confusion is that it will almost never be the case that rejecting data more than 1.54 SDs from their mean will adequately detect outliers in any normal sense of the word: there must be something very special indeed about the situation you refer to.

Comment: I can go into details on coplanarity and solder-balls if it helps.  I suspect that a review of some of JEDEC might give physical context, but insufficient technical context.  How do I determine the level of "special" of a situation?  I'm still working on the nomenclature.

Comment: @whuber -  If I have a standard normal distribution, and I take 1200 iid samples from it, then take one of those samples and replace it with a constant value.  At what point can you detect that I have done this?  If the magnitude of the constant is larger than about 2.8, then a metric like range of the data, or distance between mean and maximum tail, can indicate the presence of a replacement not from the standard normal distribution.  Is it relevant if there is a metric that can reliably detect this sort of outlier at 1.54 standard deviations from the mean?

Comment: There is no metric that can detect this "outlier" (with any reasonable probability) at $1.54$ SDs from the mean. After all, approximately an eighth of *all* the data will be further than this distance from the mean.

Comment: Even for a *uniform* distribution, about a ninth of the values will lie at least 1.54 sd's from the mean. If it's continuous, unimodal and symmetric, there will be between 11.09% and 18.74% outside 1.54 sd's from the mean.

Comment: @whuber - you are correct that it transgresses the inlier-outlier boundary.  I called them "Tiffany" from the scene in Men in black.  It is the one that doesn't belong with the others.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRXNNqNfQBs So I am hearing that just showing 1) that and 2) how such a metric might work on standard normal inlier "tiffany" excursions might have value.  Is that correct?  I think that there is a way to answer ones own question and not be a punk.

Comment: Answering your own question is perfectly fine.